# Como juntar commits específicos usando git rebase -i?

Tags: git

Como faz para juntar os commits *Limpando index* usando o `git rebase -i` pulando o commit *Removendo .env*? Sei que o `squash` junta os commits, mas, como pulo um commit específico?

Tenho o seguinte cenário: `git log`

```
commit 55ace82f06eb19553fe6e99c5154cc1e4bcedb67 (HEAD -> master)
    Limpando index

commit 68a4eedc5ee5e842a15abde159b1c339ae25bc82
    Removendo .env

commit 937d30c71dab2e82ec2a265558cc2f72ccc85333
    Limpando Index
```

Comando: `git rebase -i HEAD~3`

```
pick 937d30c Limpando Index
pick 68a4eed Removendo .env
squash 55ace82 Limpando index
```

Como pulo o commit *68a4eed* sem apagar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode reordenar seus commits e depois disso fazer o squash.

`$ git rebase -i HEAD~3`

```
pick 68a4eed Removendo .env
pick 937d30c Limpando Index
squash 55ace82 Limpando index
```

Comment: Mano, deu certo, mas o pick deve ficar no segundo commit, se não junta os três. E minha intenção é juntar os "Limpando Index" e pular o "Removendo .env". Edita a resposta para o pessoal entender.

Comment: Tranquilo, errei na hora de editar.